# How to align this logo center using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this page:

[link](http://dizievents.ch/)

I want to align and center this logo in the picture below

[image]

**CODE HTML:**

```
<span class="logo">
    <a href="http://dizievents.ch"><img src="http://dizievents.ch/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/dizi-events-3.png" alt="Logo"></a> 
</span>
```

I tried to replace this code with the following

```
   <span class="img-responsive center-block">
        <a href="http://dizievents.ch"><img src="http://dizievents.ch/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/dizi-events-3.png" alt="Logo"></a> 
    </span>
```

Can you tell me please what is wrong and what does not work?
It's something simple (I think) but I realize the problem

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the inbuilt Twitter Bootstrap class `col-md-offset-6` to align the logo. If you need to including centering in smaller devices, replace `md` with `xs` or `sm`

```html
<span class="logo col-md-offset-6">
    <a href="http://dizievents.ch"><img src="http://dizievents.ch/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/dizi-events-3.png" alt="Logo"></a> 
</span>
```

**Output:**

[image: Centered logo Bootstrap]

Answer (score 0):

Try `text-center`

```
<span class="img-responsive text-center">
        <a href="http://dizievents.ch"><img src="http://dizievents.ch/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/dizi-events-3.png" alt="Logo"></a> 
    </span>
```

Comment: It is almost good ... but why not keep in line with the same login and register buttons?

Comment: try using `col-md-offset-6` instead of `text-center`.